# go template and tab character

Tags: go, grafana, go-templates

I would like to insert tabs in a string using the go template syntax.

Basically here's my try:

```
{{ .title }}\t{{ .description }}
```

Right now what's being printed is "\t" and not an actual tab

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `\t` with a tab character or use `{{"\t"}}`.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LgptYOp8Irl).

(h/t to icza for simplification in edit)

Comment: `{{"\t"}}` (wtihout calling `print`) is also enough.